# fill up mongo data automatically by using script

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie to mongo, I have a collection in my mongodb, To test a feature in my project I need to update database with some random data.I need a script to do that. by identifying the datatype of the field script should fill up the data automatically.

suppose I have the fields in the collection:

```
id, name, first_name, last_name, current_date,  user_income etc.
```

Since the my questions are as follows:

```
 1. Can we get all field names of a collection with their data types?
 2. Can we generate a random value of that data type in mongo shell?
 3. how to set the values dynamically to store random data.
```

I am frequently putting manually to do this.

Comment: Do you need to test the random data from the Mongo Shell or would something like https://github.com/buzzm/ipsum work to create test JSON that you then import ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Can we get all field names of a collection with their data types?

mongodb collections are schema-less, which means each `document` (row in relation database) can have different fields. When you find a `document` from a `collection`, you could get its fields names and data types.

> 2. Can we generate a random value of that data type in mongo shell?
>
> 3. how to set the values dynamically to store random data.

mongo shell use JavaScript, you may write a js script and run it with `mongo the_js_file.js`. So you could generate a random value in the js script.

It's useful to have a look at the [mongo JavaScript API documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/js) and the mongo shell [JavaScript Method Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/).

Other script language such as Python can also do that. mongodb has their APIs too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I'll check for the links you referred. Will accept the answer soon. but I'm looking for something more.